# Wix installer - how to run change with administrative privileges when run from Uninstall or change program in Control Panel

Tags: installation, wix, uac, custom-action

My installer has a custom action which contacts a windows service and set some parameters.
In order to successfully use the service, it must be run with the elevated privileges.

In the first time install when a user clicks on the Install button, it is presented with the UAC prompt and install completes successfully. However, when a user decides to change the product(add new feature), call to the service will fail! This happens because installer is not run in the privileged mode. When I start the installer from a command prompt with administrative rights, change operation also completes successfully.

I've came across the following [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/48265402-1fbc-41d4-aedc-2c711750fe4a/)  which  suggests creating a bootstrapper. Is there any easier way to accomplish this?

Did I implement the custom action correctly?. Here's the custom action code

```
     <CustomAction Id='SetParams' BinaryKey='Setup.CustomAction' DllEntry='SetParameters' Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no' Return='asyncWait'/>
<Binary Id='Setup.CustomAction' SourceFile='$(var.CustomActionDll)' />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='SetParams' Before='InstallFinalize'><![CDATA[REMOVE <> "ALL"]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Update: After Cosmin's comment, I realized I was accessing the session data in CA. SetParams CA uses dynamic properties generated in the UI sequence. To access data in deferred CA, I've created an immediate CA which dynamically extracts this data and puts it in the CustomActionData.

```
<CustomAction Id='SaveParams' BinaryKey='Setup.CustomAction' DllEntry='SaveParameters' Execute='immediate'  Return='check'/>
<CustomAction Id='SetParams' BinaryKey='Setup.CustomAction' DllEntry='SetParameters' Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no' Return='check' />

<Custom Action='SaveParams' Before='SetParams'><![CDATA[REMOVE <> "ALL"]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action='SetParams' Before='InstallFinalize'><![CDATA[REMOVE <> "ALL"]]></Custom>
```

Following is the part of SaveParameters method in the custom action

```
propertyName = moduleInfo.GetPropertyName(moduleParameter.Name);
customActionData.Append(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}={1};", propertyName, session[propertyName]));
```

This approach works! 
When started from admin cmd session[propertyName] returns the correct value, but when I run the installer change from non-elevated cmd prompt, I cannot access the property values in the immediate CA - session[propertyName] returns empty string ?!

I can access the (static) property defined in wxs file

```
<Property Id="INSTALL" Secure="yes" />
```

but not the one's I've added in some other immediate custom action in the UI sequence like this

```
session[property] = parameters[paramcount++];
```

Comment: Deferred and no impersonation attributes ensure that your custom action runs with full privileges. Something else is causing the problem. Try debugging the custom action code.

Comment: @CosminPirvu I've tried running the installer (change op) from user command prompt and from administative cmd. In case of admin cmd custom action worked flawlessly, while in the case of regular cmd it acts the same as when change is started from control panel. Evidently, the call to custom action fails because it's not run as admin.

Comment: @CosminPirvu You were right. I was accessing the session data in CA. SetParams CA uses dynamic properties generated in the UI sequence. To access data in deferred CA, I've created an immediate CA which dynamically extracts this data and puts it in the CustomActionData. This approach works! However, when I run the installer change from non-elevated cmd prompt, I cannot access the property values in the immediate CA?! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deferred custom action with no impersonation attribute set will ensure that the CA is run in elevated mode.

I've added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207744/wix-accessing-the-property-values-from-deferred-custom-action-created-dynamica) to address the other issue which emerged.

Solution to accessing dynamic property value issue

1. Immediate action which reads properties to be moved from execution
   sequence to UI sequence
2. Actions in execution phase can access data
   from secure properties as stated in the question. If the properties
   are dynamically created in CA, they must be added to
   SecureCustomProperties system property. Separator char is ';'."